# ZF3 Development Mode VS Production Mode

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I use ZF3 and code in the development mode. I configured it like the tutorial suggests:

```
composer development-enable
```

So everything works fine if this mode is enabled. If I disable it I get a database connection error, like this one:

> Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' to database 'xyz'

I still work on the same computer.

So what error it might be?

The main topic would be, how is the right way to change between development and production, does the composer statement also make clear to use the production configfiles?

If I have changed the mode via composer, what do I have to do additional? I really blueeyed thought, it would be enough to just disable:

```
composer development-disable
```

Do I have to rename the development config files also? Of which files do we talk about? Is it just `application-config.php` and `development-config.php`?

Where and how should I place the different database connections? I now use the files you see above.

And last, how to change the mode on the production server? I now just disabled the mode on my developmentsystem and then uploaded the hole project. Afterwards I only upload the changed files.

EDIT1: Here additional a screensot, which configuration files I use in which folders:
[image: Screenshot config files and folders]

In my application.config.php the configuration links to:

```
 'config_glob_paths' => [
            realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
        ],
```

and in my development.config.php the configuration links to

```
 'module_listener_options' => [
        'config_glob_paths' => [realpath(__DIR__) . '/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}-development.php'],
        'config_cache_enabled' => false,
        'module_map_cache_enabled' => false,
    ],
```

for me it looks correct. My database connection is in `local.php` (for the production) and in `local-development.php` (for the development mode).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enabling/Disabling the mode is just the same as having/not having the `config/development.config.php` file.

If you [look closely](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/development.config.php.dist), you'll see that the development mode disables the cache.

Your problem is that the cache files have been created (non dev mode) while the configuration wasn't fine for the environment. Remove `data/cache/application.config.cache` and `application.module.cache` as configured in [`config/application.config.php`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/config/application.config.php).

Comment: thanks, that was my understanding issue, now everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

If you use `development-mode enable` (**Development**) it mean `config_cache_enabled` set to `false`. So your new configuration like `module`, `services`, `controllers`, etc will load by `ZF3`, because `ZF3` will not read the configuration from `cache` (in `data/cache/*`).

If `development-mode disable` (**Production**) configuration will be cached, so when you deploy your code with new configuration like I mention above, will not read by `ZF3`. Because `ZF3` still read the configuration in `cache`.

I usually remove the cache when deploying to Production. Here the sample `shell script` I used for deploying

```
#/bin/bash
rsync --exclude data --exclude .git -av temp_example.com/. /var/www/example.com/.
echo -e "Removing cache..."
rm  -f /var/www/example.com/data/cache/*.php
```

So, the main key, if you used `development-mode disable`, just remove the `cache` after deploying the code.