# Zend 3 Doctrine ORM can't find entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I have recently updated my 3 entities - let's call then EntityA, EntityB and EntityC. Now I can't retrieve data or delete a record from EntityB and EntityC. I can insert and update though. EntityA still works fine.

Changes are as follows:

I updated a column from int to bigint and changed an index on EntityA.

I updated an index for EntityB and EntityC. EntityC also has a few new columns.

EntityB and EntityC both have a foreign key constraint linked to the id of EntityA. I am using a manyToOne relationship:

```
/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

I had just seen a comment on another question about validating the schema and after using `orm:validate-schema` I did have a sync issue with my db:

[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.

[Database] FAIL - The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

I used `orm:schema-tool:update --force` to correct the problem:

[Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.

[Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

After this I cleared all 3 caches using:

```
orm:clear-cache:query    
orm:clear-cache:metadata
orm:clear-cache:result
```

Any idea why I still can't access data from EntityB and EntityC?

**EDIT**

I'm new to doctrine and I manually updated the db and entities which seems to have caused this issue. Should I export the data, drop the tables, delete the entities, recreate all and import the data back? How should I update my db and entities in the future?

**EDIT 2**

I should also mention everything was working perfectly fine before I made the changes listed above and the changes do not include the foreign key constraint. That was there from the start when everything worked. Looking at the code again I realise that delete may actually be working, but the code fails before it gets there when trying to retrieve the record:

```
$this->entityManager->getRepository(EntityC::class)->findOneBySomeField($details['someField']);
```

Comment: You should provide the actual code that fails (delete entity C).

Comment: Like I said in my comment on your previous question, which you deleted and have reposted as this one, you need to post your code. Though this one is a lot better, we cannot reproduce the issue on a simple "it doesn't work". Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then update your question with the code your executing, such as the contents of `function findOneBySomeField` in the repo for `EntityC`. You must also post all relational Annotation of the Entities.

Comment: @rkeet thanks for the advice. Unfortunately I can't share more, but findOneBy is a doctrine EntityRepository method. I'm just using SomeField rather than the actual field name. The only changes that have been made are the ones I have mentioned. The code worked fine for months prior to these changes and then it just broke. I realise it is difficult to debug without more info. I guess I'm just hoping someone has had a similar issue after manually updating their db and entities.

Comment: alright then. Have you deleted all Proxy cache classes? (in the `data/` folder)

Comment: Just did, but still no luck. var_dump($this->entityManager->getRepository(EntityA::class)->findOneBySomeField($details['someField'])); outputs the correct object, but EntityB and EntityC output a 404.

Comment: Have you possibly moved the Entity classes and do they now reside in a different folder and is the namespace not updated? Are the modules loaded via Composer (have you checked in the autoloader of composer?) and are they loaded via ZF config?

Comment: I also thought maybe classmaps / autoloads need an update: `composer dump-autoload`. But why do you think Doctrine returns a 404 HTTP status code, it doesn't. Maybe you have a Zend_Route not configured and the problem is not even Doctrine related.

Comment: Ok so I haven't moved the Entity classes and composer just has `"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Application\\": "module/Application/src/"
        }
    },`. I tried `composer dump-autoload`, but didn't help. My routes have not changed, but just came across something interesting. If I `var_dump($this->entityManager->getRepository(EntityC::class)->findOneBySomeField($details['someField']));` using a value for $details['someField']) that does not exist in the db I get a response of null. When I  use a value that does exist it actually causes a 500 internal server error.

Comment: I actually had a problem at the start of this project some months ago and I shared some of the code because it didn't yet have anything specific. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49129078/5133172